# Firebase Cloud Functions Object possibly 'undefined'

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have the following code in typescript and i get this error on the line: `change.after.data();`, Object is posibbly 'undefined':

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

admin.initializeApp()

export const onEditModeUpdate = 
functions.firestore.document("Settings/ShiftsEditMode").onUpdate(change=> {
    const after = change.after.data();
    const payload = {
        data: {
            temp: String(after.temp),
            conditions: after.conditions
        }
    }
    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("Settings/ShiftsEditMode", payload)
})
```

[image]
what I want to do is to send to my app a notification whenever something in firestore changes, I followed the official documentation but I get the error, I think this has to do with node.js version. Any help, please?

Comment: Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `change` parameter is of type Change.  If you click through to it in VSCode, you'll see it's definition here:

```
export declare class Change<T> {
    before?: T;
    after?: T;
    constructor(before?: T, after?: T);
}
```

Notice that its `before` and `after` properties are both optional, marked with a `?` in the type.  This means that it's possible that the values are undefined.

It's likely that your TypeScript config in `tsconfig.json` contains a line for `"strict": true`, which tells TypeScript not warn you whenever you try to access a property that could be undefined without explicitly checking it first.  That's the error you're seeing here.

You have two options:

1) Remove that line from your tsconfig.json

2) Or check to see if it's defined first

```
if (change.after) {
    const after = change.after.data();
    const payload = {
        data: {
            temp: String(after.temp),
            conditions: after.conditions
        }
    }
    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("Settings/ShiftsEditMode", payload)
}
else {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was following your tutorial in a social network. Thanks again it did the trick :)

Comment: The default addition of strict: true is pretty recent for projects created with the Firebase CLI, and my tutorials actually don't use that.  So it's kind of a bummer that today's defaults no longer match the tutorials.

Comment: Another thing if it is possible, i get this error in function logs when i change the data: Messaging payload contains an invalid value for the "data.conditions" property. Values must be strings.

Comment: That sounds like a completely different thing.  Please post a separate question about that one.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the types for the `onUpdate` handler, the argument for `change` has 2 optional properties, `after` and `before`:

```
class Change<T> {
    before?: T;
    after?: T;
    constructor(before?: T, after?: T);
}
```

Because you want to access `after`, you'll need to wrap it in a conditional, something like this following:

```
functions.firestore.document("Settings/ShiftsEditMode").onUpdate(change=> {
    if (change.after) {
        const after = change.after.data();
        ...
    }
}
```