# Firebase cloud functions ts2532,7005

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have been watching Cloud Functions videos
and I still got issues so I decided to ask here

and I have already checked this out link: [Firebase Cloud Functions Object possibly 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55167069/firebase-cloud-functions-object-possibly-undefined)

but the problem is still not working

first of all, I do not want to delete "strict mode" in tsconfig.json

here is my code

```
export const onBostonWeatherUpdate =
functions.firestore.document("cities-weather/boston-ma- 
us").onUpdate(change => {
if (change.after) {
const after = change.after.data() 
const payload = {
    data: {
        temp: String(after.temp),
        conditions : after.conditions
    }
}
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("weather_boston-ma-us", payload)
.catch(error => 
    console.error("FCM failed", error))
}
else{
    return null
}
})
```

this makes ts(2532) Object is possibly 'undefined'.
and I do not want to use "after!" either because what if it`s really undefined in some case

and

```
.then(citySnapshots => {
    const results = []
    citySnapshots.forEach(citySnap => {
        const data = citySnap.data()
        results.push(data)
    })
    response.send(results)
})
```

this makes ts(7034) Variable 'results' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.

I really have been stuck for this for long time

now please somebody help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
const after = change.after.data()
```

`data()` can return undefined if the snapshot doesn't exist.  You need to check for that case before using `after`.

Comment: yes, so I used that line " if(change.after) " it is supposed to be to ensure that it is not undefined but it is not

Comment: Your code is not checking if `data()` returns undefined.  You are only checking if `change.after` is undefined.

Comment: you mean if (change.after){
    const after = change.after.data() 
    if (after){              right?