# Object is possibly undefined even if I check if it exists with a conditional

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a typescript cloud function for Firebase. Even if I check if change.after exists like mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55167069/firebase-cloud-functions-object-possibly-undefined), I still get Object possibly undefined error.

Here is my code:

```
export const toDashboardInfo = functions.firestore.document('maps/{mapId}').onWrite((change, context) => {  
  let userId;
  if(change.after){
    const after=change.after.data();
    userId=after.ownerId;
  }
```

Here is a screenshot in vscode:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mentioned, you're checking if the `change.after` exists. When it does, you call a method on it called `data()` which can return `FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData` or `undefined`. That means the variable `after` can be either of those types as the result of `data()` method could have returned `undefined`.

You should also check if the `typeof after !== 'undefined'` before accessing its property.

```js
export const toDashboardInfo = functions.firestore.document('maps/{mapId}').onWrite((change, context) => {  
  let userId;
  if (change.after) {
    // change after exists
    const after = change.after.data();

    // after can be undefined as data() could return undefined
    if (typeof after !== 'undefined') {
      userId = after.ownerId; // it's safe to access ownerId
    }
  }
}
```

Also, if you're using typescript v3.7 and higher, you can make use of [Optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining). The code would then look similar to:

```js
export const toDashboardInfo = functions.firestore.document('maps/{mapId}').onWrite((change, context) => {  
  const after = change.after?.data();
  const userId = after?.ownerId || 'default value';
}
```

You can skip the `|| 'default value'` part if `userId` can be `undefined` when no data or `ownerId` is returned.